# Chart doesn´t show data from database/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive, syncfusion-chart

Hey guys i created an App where data is shown in a chart. My problem is that the data isn´t shown but I don´t know why

here is my chart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'data.dart';

class DataChart extends StatelessWidget {
  String val1 = "";
  double pot1 = 0;
  String val2 = "";
  double pot2 = 1;
  String val3 = "";
  double pot3 = 2;

  final hiveBox = Hive.box<Data>('dataBox');
  //late List<Data> data = dataFromHiveBox;

  late List<Data> data = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SfCartesianChart(
          primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(),
          series: <ColumnSeries<Data, num>>[
            ColumnSeries<Data, num>(
                dataSource: data,
                xValueMapper: (Data data, _) => data.Fehlstellung,
                yValueMapper: (Data data, _) => data.Wiederholung,
                dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }}
```

and here is how it looks:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8p2v.jpg)

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you assign value to your list of data because it looks like empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
SfCartesianChart(
            title: ChartTitle(text: 'Flutter Chart'),
            legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
            series: <ColumnSeries<Data, num>>[
              ColumnSeries<String, num>(
                  dataSource: data,
                  xValueMapper: (Data, _) => data.Fehlstellung,
                  yValueMapper: (Data, _) => data.Wiederholung,
                  dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true)
              ),
            ],
            tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior( enable: true),
          )
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I tried it and it shows me the error :                                                                                                                                                ````The element type 'ColumnSeries<String, num>' can't be assigned to the list type 'ColumnSeries<Data, num>'.````

Comment: Oh sorry, using 'ColumnSeries<Data, num>' instead of ColumnSeries<String, num>